# add multiple records in textfile

Tags: java

I want to add multiple records in a textfile. So I wrote the following program. But in this program data is overwrite every time user enters data from command prompt. In file data is overwrite. So How to add multiple records in a text file?

apples3.java

```
class apples3
{   public static void main(String[] args)
    {   ffile g = new ffile();
        g.get();
        g.openFile();
        g.addRecords();
        g.closeFile();
    }
}
```

ffile.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ffile
{   private Formatter x;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int rollno;
    String fname, lname;
    public void get()
    {   System.out.println("Enter rollno: ");
        rollno = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter first name: ");
        fname = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter last name: ");
        lname = sc.next();
    }
    public void openFile()
    {   try
        {   x = new Formatter("xyz.txt");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {   System.out.println("You have an error");
        }
    }
    public void addRecords()
    {   x.format("%s %s %s ", rollno, fname, lname);
    }
    public void closeFile()
    {   x.close();
    }
}
```

After adding a record i display it using the following code snippet:

```
Scanner x;
            try
            {   x = new Scanner(new File("Keyur.txt"));
                while(x.hasNext())
                {   String a = x.next();
                    String b = x.next();
                    String c = x.next();
                    String d = x.next();
                    System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s\n", a, b, c, d);                     
                }
                x.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {   System.out.println("could not find file");
            }
```

the output of the display is as following in cmd:
1 ghi mno
2 xyz abc
3 pqr def

Actually i am running this program in my java frame. so i take all the necessary textbox, label, button.
 when i enter any name in textbox then that names' particular row i want to delete such as i enter xyz then delete row 2 xyz abc from database txt file.
and i write pqr in textbox and in second textbox aaa then i want to update that record in my txt file.

so if this possible then i want only code snippet then it is also useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try opening the stream in [append mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.lang.String,%20boolean)):

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("xyz.txt", true);
x = new Formatter(fos);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works But when record is added then i want that it added in a new line. So that i wrote the code `x.format("%s %s %s \n", rollno, fname, lname);`  But it not works..

Comment: for new line you can add this : `x.format("%s", "\n");` Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 2):

According to Java Doc every time you create a Formatter object it will overwrite the file.You can see it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter(java.lang.String)). Try this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ffile
{   
    private File file;
    BufferedWriter output;
    private Formatter x;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int rollno;
    String fname, lname;
    public void get()
    {   System.out.println("Enter rollno: ");
        rollno = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter first name: ");
        fname = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter last name: ");
        lname = sc.next();
    }
    public void openFile()
    {   try
        {
        x = new Formatter();
        file = new File("xyz.txt");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {   System.out.println("You have an error");
        }
    }
    public void addRecords()
    {   
        try {
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));
            output.write(x.format("%s %s %s \n", rollno, fname, lname).toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void closeFile()
    {   
        x.close();
        try {
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
public void openFile() {
try {
        // APPEND MODE SET HERE
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("xyz.txt", true));
        x = new Formatter(bw);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("You have an error");
    }
}

public void addRecords() {
    x.format("%s %s %s", rollno, fname, lname);
    x.format("%s", "\n");
}
```

Comment: For new line i write:   `x.format("%s", "\n");`  and also i try to write with `x.format("%s %s %s \n", rollno, fname, lname);`  and also i try to write with the code `x.format("\n %s %s %s", rollno, fname, lname);`  But it not works.

Comment: I have Windows 8.1 and my jdk is jdk1.8.0_05.

Comment: well, my installed version of jdk is different from yours.I'm using Ubuntu and my jdk version is jdk1.6. Not sure but I'll test it with your one also. :)